# ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block --- export data from Aqua studio

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to export one table from Aquastudio into CSV file. The table has approximately 4.4 million rows. When I am trying to use the export window function in the aqua studio, I am facing the following error:

> Error: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I am not understanding what the problem is. I read few articles regarding this error and found that this is happening due to some error in the last postgreSQL command. I did not use any SQL commands for this export and I dont know how to debug this. I am also unable to view the log files.

Comment: Find the *first* error, it'll tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I don't know Aquastudio, but is there any code you can show us? Could you provide a [mcve]? It would help. As it stands, it's likely hard to find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be exporting millions of rows through a JDBC/ODBC connection, especially for Redshift.

For Redshift, please use the [`UNLOAD` command documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html). You'll have to `UNLOAD` the file to S3 and download it from there.

For Postgres, use [`COPY TO` as documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html).

Answer (score 13):

Use `rollback` to cancel the previous query. After that, you will be able to execute your current query.

Comment: Thanks, saves my day